# Socket.io binding - performance and memory usage

Tags: javascript, socket.io

The server side of a typical socket.io app looks like this:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("foo", function(data) {
    });
    socket.on("bar", function(data) {
    });
    [ ... ] 
    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
    });
});
```

Doesn't this mean the bindings for `foo`, `bar`, etc are done individually for each socket, for every new connection? If there are 1000 connections, wouldn't there be 1000 instances of the same `foo` callback function?

If so, since Node would be keeping 1000 anonymous-but-identical functions, wouldn't it waste a lot of memory?

Comment: What do you suggest as an alternative ?

Comment: @adeneo, using named functions defined beforehand...

Comment: @gladsocc - That would require the event to bubble, remember these aren't DOM nodes.

Comment: @jcaron - same thing, named or anonymous functions makes no difference

Comment: @adeneo not to RAM usage? for anonymous functions, isn't a new instance of the same anonymous function created for each connection?

Comment: That depends on how V8 treats functions and references, I'm not sure named functions would save you that much, but I guess you'd have to try it for yourself.

Comment: @adeneo you clearly didn't read @gladsocc's possible solution correctly. He proposed passing the socket as a parameter so there would be no need for 1000 closures to hold onto 1000 sockets. Tbh, a less-breaking solution would be to run the function in the context of the socket (ie. pass it in as `this`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across your question while Googling as I had the same concern. I figured it out but I know this is a bit old so, if it doesn't help you, hopefully it'll help anyone else wondering the same thing.

Socket.io's `Socket` class inherits from node's `EventEmitter` (as you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L77))

And as [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2683-eventemitter-invokes-event-callbacks-in-the-context-of-the-eventemitter-instance-in-node-js.htm) explains and demonstrates, EventEmitter will run your callback's in the context of the `EventEmitter` **instance** (in this case, the socket).

So for a more performant implementation of your original code (which I see *everywhere* demoing socket.io):

```
io.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    socket.on( 'foo', onFoo );
    socket.on( 'bar', onBar );
    socket.on( 'echo', onEcho );
    // ...
    socket.on( 'disconnect', onDisconnect );
});

function onFoo(data) {
    /* `this` refers to the socket */
}
function onBar(data) {
    /* `this` refers to the socket */
}
function onEcho(data) {
    /* `this` refers to the socket */
    this.emit('echo-back', data);
}
// ...
function onDisconnect() {
    /* `this` refers to the socket */
}
```